# Is it possible to use Change Tracking on a Replication target?

Tags: sql-server, replication, change-tracking

We have a setup where the production SQL Server databases are replicated to an offsite location using SQL Server Replication (transactional replication).

I am looking at using [SQL Server Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) to get the updated data in order to perform some processing and add values to a cache. Before I start down this road, does anyone know if it's possible to use Change Tracking on a replication target? It seems like it should work, but it also seems complex enough that there would be gotchas.

Comment: Hi there.  I haven't tried this but have you seen https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does anyone know if it's possible to use Change Tracking on a replication target?

When you say replication target, do you mean subscriber ? Irrespective, of it, CT will work with replication.

---

### **Things to consider when implementing Change Tracking (CT):**

- Make sure you have [retention & clean up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964713.aspx) of the data in the hidden CT tables.
- Enable CT on the tables that you need. Dont go haywire and enable it on all the tables in the database.
- Read carefully the article written by Kendra - [Performance Tuning SQL Server Change Tracking](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/performance-tuning-sql-server-change-tracking/)